# Can't render bold latex fonts in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

I have a weird issue where I can't render any bold fonts when I enable tex in matplotlib. I have the following lines in my script:

```
rc('font',family='serif',serif='cm16')
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

and if I try to make an axis label

```
plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{foo}')
```

or

```
plt.xlabel('foo',fontweight='bold')
```

nothing happens, the text appears in regular weight. I don't get any error messages when I run the script. The exact same script works fine and produces bold text if I run it on a seperate Mac desktop. FWIW the two systems I tested this on have the same matplotlib version (1.3.1) but the laptop that I have this problem on has Tex Live Debian ver. 6.1.1 and the Mac has Tex Live 6.2.0.

Have any other Linux users encountered this problem??